# Как удалить ячейки в Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, матрицы

Нужно вставить матрицу в файл Excel. Но вместе с ней вставляется то, что не нужно.

```py
import pandas as pd

n = 26 #рёбра графа
m = 21 #вершины графа
a1 = open("a.txt", "r").readlines() #в этих двух файлах содержится направления вершин,
b1 = open("b.txt", "r").readlines() #по этим вершинам создаётся граф

matrix = [[0 for i in range(m)] for i in range(m)] #заполняю матрицу нулями

for i in range(n):
    [a, b] = a1[i], b1[i]
    a,b = int(a),int(b)
    matrix[a][b] += 1
    matrix[b][a] += 1

#print матрицы в терминал для наглядности
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        print(matrix[i][j], end= " ")

pd.DataFrame(matrix).to_clipboard() #копирую матрицу в буфер обмена для себя
pd.DataFrame(matrix).to_excel("graph.xlsx",startcol=1,startrow=1,index=False) #вставляю матрицу в Excel
```

Вот такая матрица получается. Мне нужно удалить всё, что отмечено красным, а саму матрицу, то есть, то что выделено зелёным, вставить в Excel.
[image: описание1]

Однако при вставке в Excel (`pd.DataFrame(matrix).to_excel("graph.xlsx",startcol=1,startrow=1,index=False) #вставляю матрицу в Excel`) не все красные элементы удалены. Как их удалить? И вообще зачем они появляются? Боковой я смог удалить, прописав index=False, если True, то и боковой вставляется.
[image: описание2]

Comment: Причём, в терминал матрица выводится без этих лишних столбиков и строк.

Comment: `, header=False, index=False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(matrix).to_excel("graph.xlsx",startcol=1,startrow=1,header=False,index=False)
```